# How can I trigger style to ContentPresenters inside

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I want to trigger style to ContentPresenter's items.
How can I do it?

I have template like this. (almost default button style)

```xml
<Style x:Key="ImageButtonStyle2" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background3}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border3}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Foreground3}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Foreground3}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background3}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border3}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background3}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border3}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background3}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border3}"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground3}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And, I'm using button like this.

```xml
<Button x:Name="ImageButton2" Style="{DynamicResource ImageButtonStyle2}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Viewbox Width="48.000" Height="30.000">
            <Canvas Width="48.000" Height="30.000">
                <Path Fill="..." Data="..." />
            </Canvas>
        </Viewbox>
        <TextBlock Text="XXX"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

When disabling button, I want to change the Fill, Foreground and Background color of Path and TextBlock items.

I was thinking to write a Setter tag to the Trigger "IsEnable" tag... but I'm stuck with that.

Is there any good way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the same Background color of `Button` to reflect in your Path and TextBlock, You can *Bind* `Background` property of `Button` to `Path`'s `Fill` and `TextBlock`'s `Foreground` property.

```xml
<Button x:Name="ImageButton2" Height="30" Width="100">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Viewbox Width="48.000" Height="30.000">
            <Canvas Width="48.000" Height="30.000">
                <Path Fill="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}"
                      Data="..." />
            </Canvas>
        </Viewbox>
        <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}"
                   Text="XXX"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Or

If you are looking for different `Backgroud`, you can try setting Foreground using separate `Triggers`. Like,

```xml
<TextBlock Text="XXX">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}" 
                             Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```